# Chrome, how to get element css style url() from chrome Dev Tools

Tags: css, google-chrome

For example:

[image]

I try to click the right mouse button on `filter` parameters and select: "Open in new tab"

[image]

I can get this [URL](https://spready.co.jp/wp/wp-content/themes/spready/assets/css/app.css#goo).

I searched for the keyword `#goo` in this URL, but it still unable to solve the `filter` parameters:

[image]

This URL does not describe the contents of the `filter` parameters, just to list the same style code as on the web page:

[image]

Example web [URL](https://spready.co.jp/recruit/).

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. Could you clarify?

Comment: @Sethroph I have already edited, thanks.